# Maps not loading after google play services update

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm having a problem with a new project and trying to add a map fragment. Here's the errors;

```
07-10 10:22:04.184: I/Google Maps Android API(23978): Google Play services client version: 5077000
07-10 10:22:04.195: I/dalvikvm(23978): Could not find method guj.a, referenced from method gqi.a
07-10 10:22:04.195: W/dalvikvm(23978): VFY: unable to resolve static method 24936: Lguj;.a (Landroid/content/Context;)Lgri;
07-10 10:22:04.195: D/dalvikvm(23978): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
07-10 10:22:04.205: E/dalvikvm(23978): Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
07-10 10:22:04.205: W/dalvikvm(23978): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpr;) in Lgps;
07-10 10:22:04.205: D/dalvikvm(23978): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
07-10 10:22:04.205: E/dalvikvm(23978): Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
07-10 10:22:04.205: W/dalvikvm(23978): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpr;) in Lgps;
07-10 10:22:04.205: D/dalvikvm(23978): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
07-10 10:22:04.205: E/dalvikvm(23978): Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
07-10 10:22:04.205: W/dalvikvm(23978): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpr;) in Lgps;
07-10 10:22:04.205: D/dalvikvm(23978): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
07-10 10:22:04.205: D/dalvikvm(23978): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea3 at 0x0a in Lgps;.a
07-10 10:22:04.205: D/dalvikvm(23978): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea3 at 0x0c in Lgps;.a
07-10 10:22:04.205: D/dalvikvm(23978): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea3 at 0x0a in Lgps;.a
07-10 10:22:04.205: W/dalvikvm(23978): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20873 (t) in Lyp;
07-10 10:22:04.205: D/dalvikvm(23978): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
07-10 10:22:04.205: W/dalvikvm(23978): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20873 (t) in Lyp;
07-10 10:22:04.205: D/dalvikvm(23978): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000d
07-10 10:22:04.215: I/Google Maps Android API(23978): Google Play services package version: 5084038
07-10 10:22:04.455: W/ActivityThread(23978): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
07-10 10:22:04.475: I/dalvikvm(23978): Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence; interface 4023 'Lgln;'
07-10 10:22:04.475: W/dalvikvm(23978): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;' failed
07-10 10:22:04.475: E/dalvikvm(23978): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method glt.a
07-10 10:22:04.475: W/dalvikvm(23978): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2086 (Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;) in Lglt;
```

I have another app that uses maps and this is also affected by this issue. I have updated ADT and my SDK. I have also tried removing and re-adding the Google play Lib in eclipse. I've checked and regenerated my API key info.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515424/google-map-view-no-longer-loading-after-adt-upgrade-apparent-authentication-iss

Comment: @Sania I've seen that one and tried everything suggested with no joy unfortunatenly.

Comment: Is the test device also having the latest Google Play services.?

Comment: @rIHaNJiTHiN Yes it is, updated on July 2nd.